# Is it possible to lazy load background-image from css (without jQuery)?

Tags: html, css, lazy-loading

A banner has a background class

```
background {
 background-image: url("../img/background_.jpg");
 /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 height: 60vh;
}
```

Is it nowadays (2019) possible to load the image lazy? Without jQuery.

Comment: Not any way without javascript that I know about - for chrome you could try some dirty tricks using the loading="lazy" attribute on an iframe but i would not recommend this

Comment: How is the solution with javascript?

Comment: With javascript it's possible.

Comment: Can i give solution with javascript?

Comment: @ForamTrada sure

Comment: It is possible using IntersectionObserver at this moment. See:

https://www.sitelint.com/blog/lazy-loading-css-background-images-for-better-website-loading-performance/